# React prevent from toggle multiple modals

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have problem with my react app. I have generated list of 100 items. I display every element from list using map function

```
<ul className="list">
    {this.props.items.map((item) => {
      return (
        <ItemView
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          name={item.name}
          strenght={item.strenght}
          age={item.age}
        />
      );
    })}
</ul>
```

My item view display name, age and strenght. On mouseEnter display button which after click display modal under clicked element.

```
class ItemView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isMouseInside: false,
      isModalOpen: false,
    };
  }

  mouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({ isMouseInside: true });
  };

  mouseExit = () => {
    this.setState({ isMouseInside: false });
  };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <li
        onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter}
        onMouseMove={this.mouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={this.mouseExit}
      >
        <div className="item__row">
           <h5>{this.props.name}</h5>
           <h6>Age: {this.props.age}</h6>
           <p>{this.props.strenght}/100</p>

          {this.state.isMouseInside ? (
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.showForm(false)}>
              Change data
            </button>
          ) : null}

        </div>
        {this.state.isModalOpen ? (
          <Modal
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmitForm}
          />
        ) : null}
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to prevent from blocking the possibility of opening two modals or even better if after click on another button in another itemView, opened modal will be closed and suitable will open.

What happened now is I can open multiple modals and everythink works, but I want to make one modal will be displayed on page.

I tried to make another function closeModal which set state of isModalOpen to false before this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen }) in showModal function but it doesn't work.

In this app I use redux and if redux can help solve the problem I can use it.

[Visualization what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqziS.png)

CODEPEN EXAMPLE: https://codepen.io/dominik3246/pen/QqKzzp

Comment: Can you put your code working on codepen?  It will be easier for us to get our hands on the issue.

Comment: An analogous example but working the same
https://codepen.io/dominik3246/pen/QqKzzp

Comment: OK thats cool. Just to clarify your requirement - you need to have only one modal open. And when a modal is opened and 'change data' is clicked, that modal would close and the modal related to  'change data' would open?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: When you think there is a correct answer for you question(s) on stackoverflow  you should tick the 'very good' sign to mark it as your answer. When there is an answer which you think its good for a question which is not yours, you can upvote by clicking the arrow up next to the question. As you progress on SOF you will also have privileges to downvote if you deem the answer is invalid or does not follow SOF standards

Comment: Yes, I'm quite new on SOF :D Thanks for help and for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I refactored your code:

- Downgraded ItemView Class component to  container/dump-componenet. Remember, the fewer class components you have the better.
- When the button is clicked, I am storing the ID of the current item clicked in `currentItemId`
- Then I am showing the modal only if the state `currentItemId`
  matches the current item ID

I've tried my utmost to use React's pattern in the refactoring. In fact, I reduced LOC to 59 from 85 and the code IMO looks much neater now.

Use this code as a reference on how can code your React component's and containers in the future as your code needed some polishing.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/metju/pen/LzRqJp

Code:

```
class List extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            currentItemId: undefined,
            data: [{id: 0, name: "item1", strenght: 5, age: 5}, {id: 1, name: "item2", strenght: 5, age: 5}, {
                id: 2,
                name: "item1",
                strenght: 5,
                age: 5
            }, {id: 3, name: "item1", strenght: 5, age: 5}, {id: 4, name: "item1", strenght: 5, age: 5}],
        };
        this.toggleModalFunc = this.toggleModalFunc.bind(this);
    }

    toggleModalFunc(id) {
        const currentItemId = id !== this.state.currentItemId ? id : undefined
        this.setState({ currentItemId })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list">
                {this.state.data.map((d) => {
                    return (
                        <ItemView
                            key={d.id}
                            name={d.name}
                            strenght={d.strenght}
                            age={d.age}
                        >
                            <button className="btn" itemId={d.id} onClick={() => this.toggleModalFunc(d.id)}>
                                Change data
                            </button>
                            {this.state.currentItemId === d.id ? <Modal /> : null}
                        </ItemView>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
const Modal = () => (
    <div>
        THIS IS MODAL
    </div>
)
const ItemView = (props) => {
    return <li>
        <div className="item__row">
            <h5>{props.name}</h5>
            <h6>Age: {props.age}</h6>
            <p>{props.strenght}/100</p>
            {props.children[0]}
        </div>
        {props.children[1]}
    </li>
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: great, that's amazing answer :D I have only one more question. Is it hard to do to hide showed modal on second click? I mean if modal is shown then hide it on second click on button. To see the list without any displayed modals.

Comment: To hide the modal on 2nd click, just add a condition in Matthew's `toggleModalFunc`. If `id === this.state.currentItemId`, then set the state's `currentItemId` to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks @jaxx. I tested your logic. It worked. I've added it in my answer now.

Comment: @Matthew really liked the way you handled that additional condition, makes me wish I could upvote your answer again, as it's a perfect model of a concise and elegant solution. Kudos!